# BigQuery reproducing a query that use another table in a subselect

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am blocked on reproducing in BigQuery a query that is similar to the following one on MSSQL :

```
SELECT 
  COL1,
  COL2, COL3,
  CASE
    WHEN ( COL1 % 2 ) = 0 THEN COL2
    ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 COL99 FROM ANOTHER_TABLE AS AT WHERE AT.COL8 = T.COL2 AND AT.COL9 < T.COL3 ORDER BY AT.COL9 DESC)
  END AS COL4

FROM TABLE AS T
```

First, I tried to reproduce the query on BQ like the following :

```
SELECT 
  COL1,
  COL2, COL3,
  CASE
    WHEN ( COL1 % 2 ) = 0 THEN COL2
    ELSE (SELECT COL99 FROM PROJECT.DATASET.ANOTHER_TABLE AS AT WHERE AT.COL8 = T.COL2 AND AT.COL9 < T.COL3 ORDER BY AT.COL9 DESC LIMIT 1)
  END AS COL4

FROM PROJECT.DATASET.TABLE AS T
```

But it leads to the error :
`Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.`

I can understand this error, I agree that the original query is not very optimized since a subselect can be executed for every rows in the table.

Knowing that I tried the following which doesn't lead to an error but give wrong (too much) results :

```
SELECT 
  COL1,
  COL2, COL3,
  CASE
    WHEN ( COL1 % 2 ) = 0 THEN COL2
    ELSE AT.COL99
  END AS COL4

FROM PROJECT.DATASET.TABLE AS T
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
       COL99,
       COL8,
       COL9
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARITION BY COL8 ORDER BY COL9 DESC) AS rn
  ) AS TMP
  /*WHERE TMP.rn = 1*/
) AS AT
ON AT.COL8 = T.COL2
AND AT.COL9 < T.COL3
```

This query returns more rows than expected which is normal knowing the condition "AND AT.COL9 < T.COL3", but I have difficulties to find out how to take the minimum ROW_NUMBER value (rn) to reproduce the TOP 1 of the original query.

I tried to put `TMP.rn = 1` in the AT table, but the problem is that it is not always the first value that respect the condition `AND AT.COL9 < T.COL3`.

To resume, my goal is to be able to reproduce the first query at the top of this question on BigQuery, I've tried something but I am blocking on the how to take the minimum value of ROW_NUMBER (rn) matching the condition `AND AT.COL9 < T.COL3`.

Did anyone had a similar use case by any chance ?

Edit : Adding input and output :

- TABLE AS T :

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | AAA | 25/12/2022 |
| 1235 | BBB | 25/12/2022 |
| 1236 | CCC | 25/12/2022 |
| 1337 | AAA | 24/12/2022 |
| 1238 | AAA | 23/12/2022 |
| 1239 | AAA | 22/12/2022 |

- ANOTHER TABLE AS AT

| COL99 | COL8 | COL9 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | AAA | 25/12/2022 |
| 2222 | BBB | 25/12/2022 |
| 3333 | CCC | 25/12/2022 |
| 9999 | AAA | 23/12/2022 |
| 8888 | AAA | 22/12/2022 |
| 7777 | AAA | 21/12/2022 |

- Expected output

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | AAA | 25/12/2022 | AAA |
| 1235 | BBB | 25/12/2022 | NULL |
| 1236 | CCC | 25/12/2022 | CCC |
| 1237 | AAA | 24/12/2022 | 9999 |
| 1238 | AAA | 23/12/2022 | AAA |
| 1239 | AAA | 22/12/2022 | 7777 |

Comment: Hi @Ferdi777, can you provide sample input and sample outpur?

Comment: I am not able to test it right now but I will update once I can, thanks for your proposal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query provided by @forpas returns good results in my example but does not return the result I am waiting for in my real use case.

But @forpas's idea inspired me and I found a way to resolve my problem.

It gives the same result in the link provided by @forpas and the query looks like this in MySQL :

```sql
SELECT T.COL1, T.COL2, T.COL3,
       CASE
         WHEN T.COL1 % 2 = 0 THEN T.COL2
         ELSE AT1.COL99
       END AS COL4
FROM FIRST_TABLE AS T 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
      AT.COL99, 
      T.COL2, 
      T.COL3, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.COL3, T.COL2, AT.COL8 ORDER BY AT.COL9 DESC) AS COUNTER 
    FROM ANOTHER_TABLE AS AT
    INNER JOIN FIRST_TABLE AS T
    ON AT.COL8 = T.COL2 AND AT.COL9 < T.COL3) TEMP
  WHERE TEMP.COUNTER = 1
) AS AT1
ON AT1.COL2 = T.COL2 AND AT1.COL3 = T.COL3 ;
```

The query might be complex for nothing and if someone has something more optimized I would be happy to try it.

Thank you @forpas for the proposal !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.COL1, T.COL2, T.COL3,
       CASE
         WHEN T.COL1 % 2 = 0 THEN T.COL2
         ELSE FIRST_VALUE(AT.COL99) OVER (PARTITION BY T.COL1, T.COL2, T.COL3 ORDER BY AT.COL9 DESC)
       END AS COL4
FROM FIRST_TABLE AS T LEFT JOIN ANOTHER_TABLE AS AT
ON AT.COL8 = T.COL2 AND AT.COL9 < T.COL3 AND T.COL1 % 2 <> 0;
```

If `COL1` is unique in the first table, you can simplify the `PARTITION BY` clause to:

```
OVER (PARTITION BY T.COL1 ORDER BY AT.COL9 DESC)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/DNJlJDM9) (for MySql but it is standard SQL).